# Rcpp/RcppArmadillo C++/R balance for Performance

Tags: c++, r, performance, rcpp

When I benchmark small chunks of code/functions written in RcppArmadillo I see sometimes incredible (55x vs R for nested for loops in simple operations) to modest(1.3x vs R for long duration functions) speed gains. Impressed with this, I decided to translate some 400 lines of code to create one C++ function(with some small adjacent C++ functions) to replace the computationally intensive body of my R application.

Old Results:
The RcppArmadillo code is running ~3x slower then native R(update- perhaps a poor benchmark - working on it). A hybrid RcppArmadillo & R variant of the code is running ~1.10 times faster then R.

Update/Lessons Learned:
The C++ intensive code is running ~6x faster than the R&C++ hybrid code. For any passer-by's the mistakes I made are the following:

- I did not account for variable instantiation in my R benchmark(unfair comparison).
- Misplaced some computations inside of a nested C++ loop. In the R variant they were outside of said loop(includes big FFT, etc). Human error.
- Large amount of function parameters were being passed (large vectors, matrices, with casting, etc). Solved this by porting more code.
- I was not handling memory efficiently. Extra copies were being made instead of just using them. These copies aided readability, but likely damaged performance. Easy to fix.
- Made use of global variables to reduce function passing over-head and remove a few large temporary vectors from some computations(vector size: 2^15).

Edit(sorry for discontinuities with the first comment on this post)
Old Questions:

- Is global variable instantiation/preliminary memory allocation advised in the RcppArmadillo code space, to save from many variable declarations in a function body/R garbage collection? Or does Rcpp handle these in as timely of a manner as R?
- Am I correct in assuming that Rcpp loses some performance due to interfacing with R(protecting variables, garbage collection, etc)? If so, where can I find the code(file name)/documentation where these operations are handled so I can learn how to work with it better.

Any practical advice appreciated. I apologize for the vague question, I am new to SO, new to the RcppArmadillo package, and haven't written C++ in 10 years.

Comment: That’s a lot (read: too many) questions for a single question. To make it quick: (1) no; (2) no; (3) no; (4) yes — all those things; but it’s not slower than R itself for any of those; it *is* slower where you need to convert/copy between R and C++ representation of objects; (5) yes, unless you do something wrong. The question is whether these gains are big enough to be worth it. A question that cannot be answered in general.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I think this is what I needed to know. I'll try lowering the parameters passed to the Rcpp function and see how it does. If all else fails I suppose my program will be close to being ported completely to C++, for which, this package(RcppArmadillo) would have been a help in doing this.

Comment: FWIW I agree with Konrad's "too many questions" here. I disagree on the broader "will it be slower".  The answer is that the _identical code on the identical machine built under identical switches_ **should of course** perform identically under all metrics.  Computers are deterministic.  If your "work code" below is clean Armadillo code, it will be the same whether or not you interface from R.  Which is not really slower than interfacing manually via `SEXP` types as we showed in benchmarks.

Comment: (And for the record I neither downvoted nor suggested to close.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The RcppArmadillo code is running ~3x slower then native R. A hybrid RcppArmadillo & R variant of the code is running ~1.10 times faster then R.

You must be copying a lot. That is simply not plausible. Maybe time to profile your code?

Take *any* posted example.  Maybe from the Rcpp Gallery which has multiple posts.  Maybe from the by now 250 (!!) CRAN packages using RcppArmadillo.  Start with something simple, and time it.

You should see the ~ 50x factor for loops converted from R to C++.  You should see something close to maybe 1.5 times faster for purely vectorized code (as R tends to do more error checking that code we write in small extensions).

*Edit:* Here is a *trivial* benchmark showing how trivial it is to set one up.  You really can (and should !!) time all portions you suspect are inefficient.  We all make errors, both in design and in execution.  The good thing is that you have both tools *and* plenty of posted examples to guide you.

```
R> Rfunc <- function(N) { s <- 0; for (i in 1:N) for (j in 1:N) s <- s+1; s }
R> Rfunc(10)
[1] 100
R> 
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction("double Cppfunc(int N) { double s=0; for (int i=0; i<N; i++) for (int j=0; j<N; j++) s++; return(s); }")
R> Cppfunc(10)
[1] 100
R> 
R> library(rbenchmark)
R> N <- 1000
R> benchmark(Rfunc(N), Cppfunc(N), order="relative")[,1:4]
        test replications elapsed relative
2 Cppfunc(N)          100   0.073    1.000
1   Rfunc(N)          100  12.596  172.548
R>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what to say about whether it is plausible or not. It may be that my benchmark is flawed as I had to use proc.time() due to how massive the code is. I'm currently working on porting more code so there isn't 20 some odd parameters (cx_vec's, cx_mat's, cx_cubes's, etc). I will update my original post when I figure out more...

Comment: See my edit right now.  Try to decompose into pieces, and then time and test these pieces.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Some of my mistakes: huge function call over-head, loop was copying too many variables internally in C++ were-as the R variant was vectorized, I misplaced a computation inside of the nested loop that in the R variant was outside of the nested loop. My benchmark was flawed because it did not instantiate all of the variables I was using, which is an unfair comparison.

I am starting to appreciate these Rcpp libraries. There's a bit of a learning curve, but the performance is worth it. Now it is running ~6 times faster then the R and C++ hybrid. Sorry my question was subpar.

Comment: Hear, hear -- that is how learning happens.  Glad you are getting it closer to what you expected.

Comment: @caseyk not sure what was used as **R** baseline, but I would advice first try to use it on Microsoft **R** (artist, formerly known as Revolution **R**) with MKL installed, see [here](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/open/). Vector/matrix code will benefit a lot from MKL multithreaded and vectorized BLAS/LAPACK. Only when this doesn't work, I would advice to dive into Rcpp

Comment: With all due respect the preceding comment is not really helpful. First off, we have not established whether BLAS/LAPACK was the bottleneck here.  Second, multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK is orthogonal to the R engine and both open-source OpenBLAS and commercial MKL can be used. Third, and most importantly, _any (Rcpp)Armadillo program will use the same BLAS/LAPACK as R_ so the change is additive and not a substitute or alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Severin. I wasn't aware of Microsoft's R features. It is wonderful to see they natively support multithreading for mundane operations. I'll have to try it sometime as it claims to have linux support. However, many of my slow operations aren't purely linear algebra, a lot of it is PDE/ODE solving and the requirement of "non-R" indexing schema. IE: I've had hand write my own functions for circulant type convolutions and other physics oddities to get the performance necessary. So as Dirk stated, the bottle-necks weren't purely linear algebra. But I like the advice!

Comment: Still wrong, there simply is no multi-threading in any R interpreter, and multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK have existed for years with goto/openblas and mkl. (But you can add OpenMP / threading in your own compiled code if you are careful; see the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) for examples.)